# Spring Loggin not showing in the console

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, logging

i am struggling with Spring Boot Loggin. I am not able to print log.info or log.error on my console.
Here is my pom.xml file and application.properties also.
I am wondering why is this behaviour happening as I do not have any specific declarations in my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.4.0-SNAPSHOT
 

com.jgeekmz
ManagementApp
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
ManagementApp
Application for Management

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nulab-inc/zxcvbn -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nulab-inc</groupId>
        <artifactId>zxcvbn</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

```
package com.jgeekmz.ManagementApp;

 import com.jgeekmz.ManagementApp.models.Post;
 import com.jgeekmz.ManagementApp.models.User;
 import com.jgeekmz.ManagementApp.repositories.*;
 import com.jgeekmz.ManagementApp.services.PostService;
 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;
```

@Controller
public class ApplicationController {
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationController.class);

```
private final VehicleRepository vehicleRepo;
private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;
private final LocationRepository locationRepo;
private final PostService postService;
private final PostRepository postRepo;
private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public ApplicationController(VehicleRepository vehicleRepo, EmployeeRepository employeeRepo, 
LocationRepository locationRepo, PostService postService, PostRepository postRepo, UserRepository 
userRepository) {
    this.vehicleRepo = vehicleRepo;
    this.employeeRepo = employeeRepo;
    this.locationRepo = locationRepo;
    this.postService = postService;
    this.postRepo = postRepo;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

//Index page plus count vehicles, users, employees, locations. Find all posts.
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String goHome(Model model) {
    // System.out.println(model);
    // System.out.println(repo);
    // long t = repo.count();
    // System.out.println(t);
    // System.out.println(postRepo);
    model.addAttribute("tcount", vehicleRepo.count());
    model.addAttribute("empcount", employeeRepo.count());
    model.addAttribute("locations", locationRepo.count());
    model.addAttribute("posts", postRepo.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("tusers", userRepository.count());
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String goDashboard() {
    return "/index";
}

//Add new post on the index page
@RequestMapping(value = "/index/addNewPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewPost(Post post) {
    System.out.println(post);
    postService.save(post);
    return "redirect:/index";
}

//@GetMapping("/users/checkUser")
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/checkUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView checkUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, RedirectAttributes redir) {
    //User usr = new User();
    String usrName = user.getUsername();
    log.info("User" + usrName);
    User userName = userRepository.findByUsername(usrName);
    Boolean checkUserValidation;
    checkUserValidation = userRepository.findByEnabled(usrName);

   /* User valid = userRepository.findByEnabled(usrName);
    System.out.println(valid);*/

    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/login", true);
    RedirectView redirectViewTwo = new RedirectView("/index", true);
    redir.addFlashAttribute("messageUserNotExist", "User is not being registered!");
    // redir.addFlashAttribute("messageUserExist", "User already exist!");

    log.error(">>>> Logged user: " + userRepository.findByUsername(usrName));

    if (userName != null) {
        if (checkUserValidation) {
            log.error("User exist!");
            System.out.println("Logged in!");
            System.err.println("This is an error message");
            return redirectViewTwo;
        }
    }
    log.error("User does not exist!");
    return redirectView;
}

/*  //Going to home page
@GetMapping("/index")
public String goHome () { return "index"; }*/

@GetMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    return "login";
}

@GetMapping("/changePassword")
public String changePassword() {
    return "changePassword";
}

@GetMapping("/logout")
public String logout() {
    return "login";
}

 /*  @GetMapping("/register")
public String register(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) { return "register"; }*/

@GetMapping("/blank")
public String getBlank() {
    return "blank";
}
```

}

[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNQbP.png)

Comment: Firts of all ! REMOVE THE PASSWORD from the `application.properties`

Comment: Try `logging` conf keys

Comment: Hello, Zorglube, I have tried with loggin.level and etc., also with hibernate properties, but nothing is helping. Also the system.out.println() is not working. I am not able to debug anything. Have removed the pass!!! THANKS! Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you tried using `Slf4j`, I'm usiing it with Spring boot it work perfectly fine.

Comment: Or try @Beppe-C solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable logging in the application.properties

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.com.jgeekmz=DEBUG

logging.pattern.console=%clr(%5p) [%logger{0}] %m%n
```

Comment: I have added the properties, but nothing prints out on the console, yet. Yesterday was working fine, but today crashed.

Comment: Maybe some dependencies import log4j and there is some conflict. Another option is to import log4j and define a log4j.properties with the Log4J configuration.

Comment: Yes, maybe, but the system.out.println is also not able to print. Is that issue also with dependency connected, I assume nope?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add logback.xml file if you want to specify what you want to do, you have to add it in the ressources folder:

Here is an example where you can log a specific package if you want ... :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="5 minutes">
    <property name="LOG_ROOT" value="logs" />
    <property name="application-name" value="ms-pilotage" />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout"> <Pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyyHHss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n </Pattern> </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_ROOT}/${application-name}.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT}/archives/${application-name}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</FileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>200</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%-26(%d{HHss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{32} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
        <Append>false</Append>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
        <queueSize>1000</queueSize>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" additivity="false">
        <level value="TRACE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"></appender-ref>
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>


</configuration>
```

Comment: I will try, but why System.out.println is not printing, which is also strange. Will give feedback!

Comment: What ide are you using?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ, but yesterday I was able to find out my problem. As I am using Spring Security and my user is authenticating within mySQL DB, I was using this service. I my method to particular mapping was not working at all. The logging and the println statements in other methods were working fine. I also removed all dependencies and add them again. For now is ok. I will add my maapping to see it.

Answer (score 0):

nope still not able to do logging on the console. I have added dev-tool dependency, but nevertheless not possible to print any kind of debug trace.

My check mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public RedirectView checkUser(User user, RedirectAttributes redir) {
    System.out.println("HERE!");

    //User usr = new User();
    String usrName = user.getUsername();
    User userName = userRepository.findByUsername(usrName);
    Boolean checkUserValidation;
    checkUserValidation = userRepository.findByEnabled(usrName);

    /* User valid = userRepository.findByEnabled(usrName);*/

    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/login", true);
    RedirectView redirectViewTwo = new RedirectView("/index", true);
    redir.addFlashAttribute("messageUserNotExist", "User is not being registered!");
    redir.addFlashAttribute("messageUserExist", "User already exist!");

    if (userName != null) {
        if (checkUserValidation) {
            System.out.println("User is logged in!!!!!!!!!!!" + 
            userRepository.findByUsername(usrName));
            System.out.println("HERE!");
            return redirectViewTwo;
        } else {
            System.out.println("FALSE");
        }
    }
    return redirectView;
}
```

And my Spring Security settings:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/registerPage2", "/login", "/confirm","/users/**", 
            "/resources/**", "/css/**", "/js/**" ,"/fonts/**", "/img/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/checkUser")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index",true)

            .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
}
```

Basically I want to let the admin person to activate the account first, then the user to receive an email with confirmation message that his account is now active and he can log in. My idea was to do this mapping make the check and than let him login. But I assume this mapping was not working as I am using Spring Security and everything is there handle.

Is it my way the proper one or I should implement UserDetailService and use it.

Also my login form section:

```
  <form class="login-form" th:action="@{/checkUser}" method="post" th:object="${user}">

<!-- Success Massage for the user after registration -->
<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px; color: #797979; font-weight: bold">
  <span style="color: yellow;" th:utext="${message}"></span>
  <span style="color: yellow;" th:utext="${messageUserNotExist}"></span>
</div>
<div class="login-wrap">
  <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <!--<label class="checkbox">
       <span class="pull-right"><input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="lsRememberMe()"></span>
  </label>-->

  <span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" value="lsRememberMe" id="rememberMe"> Remember me </span>
  <span class="pull-left"><a th:href="@{/forgotPassword}">Forgot Password?</a></span>
  <span><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="lsRememberMe()">Login</button></span>
  <a th:href="@{/registerPage2}" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Sign Up</a>

  <!-- <a th:href="@{/users/checkUser}" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block"> Login</a> -->
  <!-- <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="lsRememberMe()"> -->
  <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="lsRememberMe()">Login</button> -->
</div>
```